# jasper studio strange sliding issue

Tags: jasper-reports, frame, sliding

LS,

I have some strange sliding issues and can't figure out why.
These are the first object of the Title part below the address labels.

So first the image in design mode.

You are looking at the top six frames. ( yes, two white ones below the pink and red one ( cut off ))
[image: design mode with 4 frames, each containing 3 text fields]

The top two frames have a fixed position, can stretch with overflow. All text fields inside are fixed.
The bottom four frames can stretch and will float as the top two frames will stretch ( as the frames are defined a little small than the font size ).

This does result in the following when rendered( see picture ) 
[image: Preview of rendered result]

The proforma invoice and our ref ( and your ref ( right )) are two more frames that are defined like the frames in the second row.

So there are two things I can't figure out :
1. Why is the frame with 'Debtor No.' in it placed so low ? It should draw next to 'INVOICE NO.' as the frame with 'Due date' isn't over flowing and they aren't overlapping with the 'INVOICE NO.' frame ?
2. Why is the frame with 'Debtor No.' stretching ? All the text fields are not overflowing.

This used to work perfectly, but with recent versions of jasper ( now working with 6.3.1 ) quality seems to be going down the drain. ( imho )

TIA

Comment: You should post the sample (the *jrxml* file) to reproduce the issue. I suppose that problem in ***positionType*** of an element. Try to set **Float** value

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Problem not yet solved, but maybe getting there.
When editing my data file to remove all customer data, the problem more or less got fixed.

Apparently the Delivery address or contents there of are pushing the 'column' with debtor etc down, which I get, sort of. 
Now, I am wondering why this isn't happening in the 'column' with the invoice date etc in it.

I'll look into this a bit further and post final answer and/or the files.

Comment: You should plat with *positionType*s. Maybe you should add external frame (for both frames in one row)